# Symbolizing the statement "Everyone likes at least two people".

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 80)

> **Example 2.2.2**
>
> **2**. *Everyone likes at least two people.*

The symbolisation given in the book is:
$$
\forall x \exists y\exists z(L(x,y) \land L(x,z) \land y \neq z)
$$

My symbolisation is:
$$
\forall x \exists y\exists z(L(x,y) \land L(x,z) \land x \neq y \land y \neq z \land x \neq z)
$$

In that same page, the author specifies that the statement means that everyone likes at least two *different* people. The symbolisation given by the author does not out rule the possibility that a person loves himself/herself, I think, so I added $x \neq y$ and $y \neq z$.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: So you think that nobody likes him(her)self. That is a possible point of view but not mainstream. I would even call it "extremely anti-human".

Comment: Hahaha. That's really good, @JCAA. You made me laugh. If a person loves himself/herself and another person, that does not count as two different people. What do you think ? I interpret the statement as meaning two different people other that him/(her)self.

Comment: The predicate $L(x,y)$ can be defined to have $x \neq y$.  If you do that, you don't have to make $x$ different from $y,z$

Comment: I would guess that $L(x,x)\land L(x,y)\land x\ne y$ suffices as an instance of "$x$ likes two different people." Clearly $x$ likes $x$ and $x$ likes $y$ - if $x\ne y$ then $x$ and $y$ are different people so...

Comment: @JCAA I'm certainly not a fan of me.

Comment: For some reason you equalize "love" and "like". Most humans like themselves and your understandjng is wrong. Some people hate themselves (this is true for some characters in Dostoevsky books, for example).

Comment: Thank you Ross Millikan and R.Burton. You are right, @R. Burton. Thank you. I understand, now.

Comment: @R.Burton: A can of cold beer can cure this.

Comment: Most humans like/love and/or like/love themselves. There are many possible combinations. In any case, that distinction doesn't matter to the exercise. If we replace each instance of "like" with "love", that same question arises. Two _different_ people taking into account oneself or not ? @R. Burton clarified this issue with his comment.

Comment: @F.Zer Yours is the most reasonable assumption. IMHO it should be accepted as a correct answer. +1

Comment: Thank you, @Dan Christensen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The symbolization given by the author does not out rule the possibility that a person loves himself/herself,

Certainly, but that is not a restriction that is indicated by *the statement* "Everyone likes at least two people".  So why would you think that you need to add it?

Just translate what is literally said.

Comment: I get it. We are not talking about the real world where decision makers are required to make reasonable assumptions when something is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement said, “Everyone likes at least two **other** people,” yours would be the correct interpretation. Since it doesn’t, $\forall x \exists y\exists z(L(x,y) \land L(x,z) \land y \neq z)$ is the correct one. By tautology, everyone is a person and is thus included in the set of all people from which the aforementioned “two people” are being drawn. By contradiction, no one is *another* person, because that would mean $\exists x(x\neq x)$!

Now, in ordinary English communication, it could be reasonable to read, “Everyone likes at least two people,” as implicitly excluding the case that you like yourself. This is because it’s pretty normal to interpret “like” as specifically referring to *interpersonal affection* rather than to self-esteem or narcissistic vanity. But in logic problems like this, we don’t do that, because that would be more mathematically complicated. It would require that $L(x,x) \rightarrow \bot$ be part of the definition of the $L$ predicate, and nothing to that effect is specified in the natural-language statement.